# Remove empty BBcode url tags with php

Tags: preg-replace

I am  having some troubles with removing empty [url=http://exp.com] [/url] tags from the string.
Here is what I have, but it is incorrect bcz it removes also if there is something between those two tags.

```
$desc = preg_replace("#\[url=.*?\][(\W)]?\[/url\]#i", "", $desc);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this pattern:

```
$desc = preg_replace('~\[url=[^]]*]\s*+\[/url]~i', '', $desc);
```

The idea is to avoid the lazy quantifier using a character class that doesn't contain the closing square bracket (ie: `[^]]`).

The `\s*+` allows only white characters between the opening and the closing tags, but you can remove it if you don't need it.

Note that a closing square bracket don't need to be escaped outside a character class and must be escaped inside a character class unless it is the first character. You can write `[^]a]` or `[^a\]]` or `[^\]a]` but not `[^a]]` that is interpreted as *all characters but `a` followed by `]`*

I am surprise by what you are trying to do since `[url=www.example.com][/url]` stands for `[url=www.example.com]www.example.com[/url]`